# Cannot resolve additionalUserInfo.isNewUser(); I want to know if the user is new or existing

Tags: android, firebase

Cannot resolve `additionalUserInfo.isNewUser()`; I want to know if the user is new or existing.

Firebase Version 11.0.4

Comment: Firebase Version 11.0.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

additionalUserinfo.isNewuser() is introduced in firebase version 11.6.0  and you are using version 11.0.4 .so you can't actually use it

So just update it to 11.6.0 ;)

Comment: u were right about version but I am still struggling to implement this in my project. I have used phone authentication and wanna know whether the user is already existing or new to the system? Is there any ideas that you can suggest?

Comment: I have never used mobile authentication in my projects.So cant say anything about it but one thing you can do is to create a database and store every mobile number after authentication in db and can check if that number is already there or not. its an alternative to additionalUserinfo.isNewuser().i dont know why its not working.

Comment: okay anyway thank you;) nobody interested in firebase auth people are not replying

Comment: @Sandeep It will return true if the user has authenticated for the first time. Its working for me & i am using it in my applications.